# How to add wildcard mapping in IIS 7.5 (Classic mode)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

What is the best way to add wildcard mapping in IIS 7.5 (Classic mode)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/using-asp-net-mvc-with-different-versions-of-iis-cs) (*Creating a Wildcard Script Map* section).