# How to have static resource requests passed to MVC (IIS 7.5)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

I have an ASP.NET MVC application running on IIS 7.5. Somehow, on my machine, requests ending in '.js' are not caught by the corresponding controller action while they are on a colleague's machine.

The action has the `ActionName` attribute specified:

```
ActionName("Scripts.js")
public ActionResult ScriptsJS()
{
    ...
}
```

When I issue a request to 'Scripts.js', I get a 404 while for my colleague's machine, he gets the result of the `ScriptsJS` action.

I figure it's something I have to configure in IIS, since the same code runs fine on my colleague's machine (also running IIS 7.5).

So, how do I configure IIS to pass requests ending in '.js' to the MVC handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that installing "IIS Recommended Configuration" using the Web Platform Installer resolved this issue.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET does not process every request sent the web server, for example is does not need to handle html, jpg, css files as they exist on disk and can be sent straight to the user.  If you want to configure IIS to pass any of these files to ASP.NET then you will need to configure a Handler Mapping for your site.

For how to do this look at this question
[How to add wildcard mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861999/how-to-add-wildcard-mapping-in-iis-7-5-classic-mode)

Comment: Thanks. That technique was already applied to the code but as my answer shows, I didn't have the Microsoft-recommended IIS configuration. +1 Because your answer may be of use to others.